# How to evaluate $\lim_{x \to \pi/2}- \frac {(\sin x - 1)}{x-\pi/2}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim\limits_{x \to \pi/2}- \dfrac {(\sin x - 1)}{x-\pi/2}$$
It's answer is zero and it is evident by L hospital, but I need other theoretical way to solve this

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set $x-\pi/2=y$ and use the fact that $\sin(y+\pi/2)=\cos y$.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the limit you're trying to calculate is exactly $-\sin'(\pi/2)$ (write this out using the difference quotient definition of derivatives). But this equals $-\cos(\pi/2) = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

$$ \lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin(x)-1}{x-\frac{\pi}{2}} = \lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)-1}{x-\frac{\pi}{2}}=\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\cos(x-\frac{\pi}{2})-1}{x-\frac{\pi}{2}}$$ with $\theta=x-\frac{\pi}{2},$ $$\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\cos(x-\frac{\pi}{2})-1}{x-\frac{\pi}{2}}=\lim_{\theta \to 0} \frac{\cos(\theta)-1}{\theta}$$
the Taylor series are:
$$ \cos(\theta)=1-\frac{\theta^2}{2!}+\frac{\theta^4}{4!}+...$$

$$\lim_{\theta \to 0} \frac{\left(1-\frac{\theta^2}{2!}+\frac{\theta^4}{4!}+...\right)-1}{\theta}=\lim_{\theta \to 0}\left(-\frac{\theta}{2!}+\frac{\theta^3}{4!}+...\right)=0$$